# Blazor components wont execute any on click event handler. Blazorise ui framework and Blazor server app

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

```
@inject IJSRuntime _runtime;

<Button Clicked="OnUniClick">
    <Figure Size="FigureSize.Is128x128" Rounded>
        <FigureImage Source="@Logo" AlternateText="@Name" />
        <FigureCaption>@Name</FigureCaption>
    </Figure>
</Button> 

    @code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Logo { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public async Task OnUniClick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        await _runtime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "This is a test alert");
    }
}
```

Neither the Console.WriteLine or the alert execute when the button is clicked. This is my first time using Blazor and I am just trying to get a JavaScript alert to pop up. I believe that I am following everything described in these three posts:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0
- https://blazorise.com/docs/components/button

Comment: This looks like Net8 rendering in Static SSR mode?  What `@rendermode` directive do you have set on the page. or set on `Routes` in `App.razor`?

Comment: It was static, I did not know that interactivity was turned off by default on when using SSR, because of your comment pointing that out I found this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0 that showed me how to turn that on

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Net8 rendering in Static SSR mode?  You need to check  the `@rendermode` directive set on the page or on `App.razor`.